# react-globe.gl shows a distorted version of a geojson file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, geojson, webgl-globe

I did edit a geojson file and want to display it using [react-globe.gl](https://github.com/vasturiano/react-globe.gl) which is a 3D (threeJS) globe library.

When I see the file on [geojson.io](https://geojson.io) it looks perfect:
[image]

However, when it's displayed it looks like "Morocco" takes up the whole world oceans:
[image]

This is the [geojson file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamanas20/geojson/main/map4.geojson).